# Issue with clicking Drop down list using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, lxml

I am trying to save the page as entire html using selenium, page has a dropdown list in it. There are 2 elements in that list and I want to save the entire html after clicking each of them.

Below is the code I am using:

```
    devlink='http://www.t-mobile.com/content/tmo-wem/en/index/cell-phones/nokia-lumia-521.html'
    devname= devlink[devlink.rfind("/")+1:]
    ignore_tags=('script','noscript','style')
    with contextlib.closing(webdriver.Firefox()) as browser:
        browser.get(devlink) # Load page
        dropdown = browser.find_element_by_class_name('dropdown-menu')
        elements = dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
        i=0
        for element in elements:
            element.click()
            i = i+1
            time.sleep(2)
            content=browser.page_source
            cleaner=clean.Cleaner()
            content=cleaner.clean_html(content)    
            with open(str(i)+devname,'w') as f:
               f.write(content.encode('utf-8'))
```

This code is giving me a error, traceback of which looks like this `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Windows Phone\Pricing\August\2013-08-05\tmo test\tmo_us_selenium.py", line 52, in <module>
    element.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 54, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 228, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 158, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace: 
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///c:/users/abhina~1.tal/appdata/local/temp/tmpwnu8em/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7736)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///c:/users/abhina~1.tal/appdata/local/temp/tmpwnu8em/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10437)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/abhina~1.tal/appdata/local/temp/tmpwnu8em/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10456)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/abhina~1.tal/appdata/local/temp/tmpwnu8em/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10461)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/abhina~1.tal/appdata/local/temp/tmpwnu8em/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10401)`

This code is not able to click the 2 elements it is finding, please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: What is the version of selenium and Firefox that you are using? Also it would be helpful if paste the full error trace - since that would contain information about the actual error occuring

Comment: Selenium-2.33.0 and FF 22.0, I have made the changes in question to paste entire traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium 2.33 supports Firefox 21 and older. You will have to wait for the Selenium update to have it support FF 22.
Refer to [this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5869) thread for further details. There are many threads on google that discuss similar issues with Selenium 2.33 and FF 22

Comment: Normally, FF and selenium web driver compatibility issues arise only when you click or interact with page elements ( for e.g. mouse hovers). What other activities do you perform on this page other than clicking elements using the web driver?